# Is there any linux tool can find the process trace of a python program?

Tags: python, linux, debugging, python-2.7, pdb

I have a python process running now , but it hangs with no log、no exception, i don't know what's going on with it.

This bug turns out every 5 or 6 hours, so this time i don't want to kill the process and trying to find a way to trace which line it hangs.

I have tried **PStack** , but i can't understand the system call it lists.

Is there any tool can show me which line the program hangs, it will be perfect if the trace info shows in python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gdb with python: http://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html which can give you a traceback of the python stack.